# Xamarin.iOS: how to add a NavigationBar to a View

Tags: xamarin, controller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller

I work on a **Xamarin native app**, where I show a **modal view** containing a list of countries.

I would like to know if there is a way to **add a Navigation Bar** to this view **through the Controller**?

***Of course, the Navigation Bar will not contain the back arrow button, but a Title and a right button allowing to close this view.***

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The modal you present needs be wrapped in a `UINavigationController` rather than only being a `UIViewController`. This will give you a `NavigationBar`.

```
var modalViewControler = new MyModalViewController(); // UIViewController
var navigationController = new UINavigationController(modalViewController);
```

Comment: Your approach is interesting, however my ViewController inherits from a BaseViewController, and the related ViewModel is opened called from a shared NavigationService.

So I don't see where I should wrap my ViewController...

Comment: I can't provide an answer for some code I have no insight to. Provide more context and get a better answer